# An inequation $(\mu-m)^2\leq\sigma^2$ involving expectation, median and variance

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose that $\xi$ is a random variable with continuous distribution function. The expectation of $\xi$ is $\mu$, the median $m$ and the variance $\sigma^2$. Prove that
$$(\mu-m)^2\leq \sigma^2.$$

I can understand the intuition behind the equation. If a dataset biases to one side,for example $A=\{1,1,1,1,10\}$,  then the median deviates from expection a lot. The variance correspondently goes up. However, the median and the expectation can be the same even if the variance is large (consider $A=\{1,1,1,3,5,5,5\}$). The problem is, where to start a rigid proof? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This inequality, in its original form $|\mu-m|\le\sigma$ was proved by Mallows, Colin (Aug '91), see the Wikipedia section [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median#Inequality_relating_means_and_medians). (DOI: https://doi.org/10.1080/00031305.1991.10475815); and if you know of a [certain website](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sci-Hub), you can use the DOI to.....

Comment: The proof is simple: use the fact that a median minimizes the absolute deviation map $a\mapsto \Bbb E(|X-a|)$ and Jensen's inequality for the convex maps $x\mapsto x^2$ and $x\mapsto |x|$

Comment: @PrasunBiswas Thank you very much for your hint^ ^ And another guy referred me to an existing post answering my question~